# Getting parent's directory name by piping the results of dirname to basename in a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Given a path like this **test/90_2a5/Windows**

I am trying to get the result **90_2a5** using the commands `dirname` to get the path and after `basename` to get the name.

The problem occurs when i try to make it in a single line trying to pipe the results from `dirname` to `basename`.

I have tried this but seems that i am using it the wrong way.

```
path="test/90_2a5/Windows"   
finalName= basename var | dirname $path  
echo "$finalName"
```

The problem is that the *finalName* is an empty string, meaning that the results from `dirname` are not redirecting.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't pipe them, but rather pass them as parameters:

```
finalName=$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$path")")
```

Some commands quite simply do not accept input streams, but only parameters:

```
$ echo foo/bar | basename
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
$ basename foo/bar
bar
```

Comment: You can also do this `echo foo/bar | xargs basename`. Use of `xargs` makes the basename accept stream.

Comment: @jeffreyveon No, `xargs` transforms standard input to a *parameter list* for `basename`.

Comment: @l0b0 Yes, you're right. I meant to say that you can pass parameter to `basename` that way.

Comment: @jeffreyveon Except it won't work for filenames containing newlines.

Answer (score 41):

```
$ echo 'test/90_2a5/Windows' | xargs dirname | xargs basename
90_2a5
```

Comment: xargs is much cleaner than nested quotes

Comment: Notice you will need -0 if your files have spaces: `pwd | xargs -0 dirname | xargs -0 basename`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can also do it without any external program like `dirname` or `basename`, just by using the bash string manipulation operations:

```
path="test/90_2a5/Windows"
# delete from last / to end
dir=${path%/*}
# delete from beginning to last /
finalName=${dir##*/}   
echo "$finalName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ${path#*/} to strip off the characters up to the first '/'. Then use dirname to remove "/Windows".

```
finalName=$(dirname ${path#*/})
```

Comment: This still isn't retrieving the base name of the directory. Try for example with `path=/test/90_2a5/Windows`

Comment: As I interpreted it the objective was stated as <<I am trying to get the result 90_2a5>>

Comment: "... using the commands **dirname** to get the path and **after basename** to get the name."